# Entering Australia answered incorrectly on ETA and Form 1023

Tags: australia, eta

I applied for an ETA two weeks ago and was approved. When asked about criminal convictions, I put no, as there was a minor thing 20 years ago in 2002 and thought it wasn't even on my record, as I was told it wouldn't be on my record, and I have applied for jobs that required security clearance, and nothing was ever brought up, so I thought I had no record.

I just got back my FBI rap sheet report which, to my horror, actually shows a misdemeanor conviction. It was a $250 fine for giving false information to a police officer and impeading an investigation, no jail time. I honestly didn't know any of the details, as my dad's lawyer took care of it at the time, and I was told it would be expunged. I don't even remember paying for the fine, which I think my dad took care of. As I said before, I had to apply for security clearances before for work, and this never came up, so I thought it was not even on my record.

My plan is to apply for a partner visa to stay in Australia when I get there. Am I screwed now because I said no initially on the ETA as far as having a criminal record, or will it be ok if I apply for the partner visa and disclose this information then, providing a copy of my criminal background check, as I think it asks for that, as I wasn't trying to purposely mislead.

I'm not in Australia yet, but I'm travelling there in two weeks on an ETA, where I was planning on applying for the partner visa. I'm looking for some emergency guidance here, as I don't want to ruin my chances of being with my partner. An attorney had suggested filling out Form 1023 Incorrect Answer form and having that with my ETA and hope that it's not denied, but I have no idea where to send the 1023.

Any info would be most helpful, as I'm scared and freaking out right now.Has anyone had success entering Australia on an ETA having answered it no but answered yes on IPC upon entry?

Comment: Might be better on expats.

Comment: Was the attorney licensed to practice in Australia and were they qualified to give migration advice?

Comment: Yes, he is a licenced immigration attorney in Australia.

Comment: A more immediate issue is how you will answer the criminal convictions question in the [Incoming Passenger Card](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-leaving-australia/files/ipc-sample-english.pdf) that you'll fill out on arrival.

Comment: I was told to come clean and answer yes on the IPC and that they most likely will ask about it. I'm not sure if others have similar experiences and if they were successful in being granted access to enter.

Comment: Most of the documentation makes it clear that they are only care about your "substantial" criminal record, only including convictions of 12 months or more. However the form itself (at least the online version, haven't checked the app) says "any" criminal record, I'm not sure if they really mean "any" or only "substantial". When you say yes, that ask for a list of offences, but don't ask for the conviction, though there's an open "Description of the conviction" field. The actual offence will most likely be disregarded, not sure if they care about you not mentioning it, though.

Comment: On a side note, don't know if that's the case in Australia, but in other places, entering with an ETA/eVisitor/tourism visa with the _intent_ to then apply for a partner visa is not allowed. Also partner visas take a very long time to process, the chances you will get yours during your stay (or even before the ETA expires) seem to be pretty low.

Comment: Thanks. The lawyer had mentioned a Form 1023, which is an incorrect answer form, which he suggested filling out and sending in, but there's no place on the instructions where to send it. But yes, from what I have read here and other places, it's recommended not to mark yes on the ETA for anything that didnt require 12 months or more jail time but to disclose it on the IPC. It's confusing.

Comment: My initial plan was to apply for the 12 month on shore travel visa to get more time, but then I saw this snag with the ETA.

Comment: @user131937: if the lawyer tells you what form to fill out, they surely can also tell you where to sent it (and how the overall process works)

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting to hear back from him. I'm not sure how many people have had success getting into Australia on an ETA with a situation similar to mine.